# Batch file to reduce length of file name

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

i download file names like this.. batchengine-6099-1283555555-60054_20100910_0006.era and want to rename them to 60054_20100910_0006.era. The names change but format same, need for statement to rename of all big files ending in .era

Answer (score 1):

I don't have access to a Windows box, but something like:

```
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
FOR %%I IN (batchengine-*.era) DO (
    SET NAME=%%~nI
    RENAME "%%I" "!NAME:~28!%%~xI"
)
ENDLOCAL
```

Type [`FOR /?`](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/ntfor.php), [`SET /?`](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/ntset.php), and [`SETLOCAL /?`](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/local.php) in the console for all of the details on the syntax.  Hopefully I have something pretty close.  You need to introduce new variables within the loop so that you can access the *extended syntax* to subscript - e.g., `!NAME:~28!` selects the substring starting at character 28.  The `!NAME!` is a delayed expansion reference.  The need for this is explained in one of the command synopsis pages.

Comment: this seems to run thru without stopping but still no work..echo
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion 
for /f %%I IN ('dir /b batchengine*.era') DO SET [NAME=[[%%~nI]] & SET [NEWNAME=[[!NAME:~28!%%~xI]] & RENAME !NAME! !NEWNAME! & pause
pause
endlocal

Comment: If I left the ~28!.%% with the . the file name i could see as it ran was 6066..era not 6066.era?

Comment: [NAME=[batchengine1-6099-12705488236217491.GP010698_61101_20100406_000217]]
[NEWNAME=[NAME:~28.era]

Comment: after running the batch i gave the set command. this is the result of running the set command. it looks like the newname portion is not working. the batch file cannot find the file....? this is what my batch looks like echo
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion 
FOR %I IN (batchengine*.era) DO ( 
    SET [NAME=[%~nI]] 
    SET [NEWNAME=[NAME:~28.era]
    RENAME !NAME! !NEWNAME! 
) 
ENDLOCAL

Comment: I think that I see the problem.  I forgot that `%%~xI` includes the `.` from the extension.  I corrected my answer with one that I actually tested this on my Windows box.